# Downloading a podacts

Tags: python, audiosegment

I am trying to dwonload some podcasts and title them accordingly.  Here is my code

```
s_out_dir = os.path.join(source_dir, pod_label, owner)
  source_file = s_out_dir + '/' + pod_title + '.mp3'
  audio_file_name = wget.download(link, out=source_file)
  try:
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(audio_file_name)
    #audio_file_name = source_dir + '/' + pod_label + '/' + owner + '/' + pod_title + '.wav'
    audio_file_name = s_out_dir +  + '/' + pod_title + '.wav
    sound.export(audio_file_name, format="wav")
    return audio_file_name
  except:
      print(audio_file_name)
```

The  code workd if i replace source_file like

```
source_file = s_out_dir + 'tmp.mp3'
```

Having the same issue saving the .wav files

Any help appreciated